# Speed and Time - finding average speed

Tags: computational-mathematics

A person wanted to travel from charbag to aalambag with an average speed of $60$km/h by car. The distance between the two cities is $2$ km. Due to traffic he could travel at $30$ km/h for the first km. What should his speed be for the remaining journey to achieve his average speed target of $60$km/h.

a) can't achieve his target with any finite speed.
b) $60$km/h
c) $90$km/h
d) $120$km/h

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please show us what you have tried. Are you having difficulties with some concept? Is your calculation wrong? Questions showing no effort tend to be voted down and/or closed.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for average speed is $$v_{avg} = \frac{\text{total distance}}{\text{total time}}= \frac{d_1+d_2}{t_1+t_2}$$

$$d_1= 1\text{km},v_1 = 30\text{km/h} \implies t_1 = \frac{1}{30}h$$

$$d_2 = 1\text{km},v_1 = x\text{km/h} \implies t_1 = \frac{1}{x}h$$
So, $$60 =  \frac{1+1}{\frac{1}{30}+\frac{1}{x}}$$

Find $x$ from here if possible (finite positive value) , otherwise he can't achieve his target with any finite speed.

Comment: That's the average of speeds, not the average speed.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei corrected it